# "Within a year or so of becoming director in Paris, he had been diagnosed as HIV positive"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> Conducting seemed to offer a fresh career, and in addition he had plans for creating several further ballets. Unfortunately his declining health prevented this. **Within a year or so of becoming director in Paris, he had been diagnosed as HIV positive**.

<sup>([Source: The Rudolf Nureyev Foundation](http://www.nureyev.org/rudolf-nureyev-biography-last-years-1993/))</sup>

Can you explain to me why the past perfect there is used in the above sentence? If I understand the phrase "within a year or so", Nureyev firstly became a director in Paris and just then he was diagnosed as HIV positive.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is used here because we're looking at the diagnosis from the perspective of a year or so after his becoming director.

I'm not certain you understand the phrase "within a year or so" - it means *at some point between when he became director and a year or so after that.*  Not necessarily just then, and not necessarily a year afterwards, just somewhere in there.  His diagnosis occurred some time between becoming director and a year or so afterwards.  So by the time that year or so was up, we say he *had been diagnosed* because it was a completed event by that point.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But is it not almost certain that the diagnosis happened after his appointment as a director? Would it happen to a change in the meaning when using just a simple past ("was diagnosed")?

Comment: Yes, the diagnosis happened after his appointment.  But exactly when is unclear.  You ask a good question about the difference with the simple past!  In practice I think there is very little difference in meaning between *was diagnosed* and *had been diagnosed*.  *had been diagnosed* does a slightly better job of expressing that the diagnosis was complete by the end of a year; that it *had occurred* during that year.  *was diagnosed* would fit better with a specific time period in which it occurred, like "was diagnosed in January 1992".

Comment: +1. The first sentence in this answer hits the nail on the head.  The vantage point is the year-or-so *after* his appointment as director. That is a point in the past. Date Math: add ~11-15 months to the appointment date.  Within the  time-window  established by those two endpoints, the latter of which is a little fuzzy, but both of which are in the past (Appointment Date .... 11-15 months later) there had been a diagnosis.